# SQL - finding max date

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have some data with 2 date fields: `record date` and `purchase date`.

Record date is the first day of every month:

```
2016-01-01
2016-02-01
2016-03-01
```

Purchase date is the date that a product is purchased:

```
2015-02-14
2016-01-06
```

What I need to do is take the most recent purchase date for every record date. So NOT the most recent purchase date overall, which is what `MAX(purchasedate)` gives me. But the max purchase date BEFORE record date.

So my resulting dataset for the examples I have listed above would be:

```
Record Date          Most Recent Purchase Date
2016-01-01           2015-02-14
2016-02-01           2016-01-06
2016-03-01           2016-01-06
```

Comment: please tag your dbms.

Comment: Cant you group by DATE(Record Date) and select max(purchase date)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use window function `max` for find the latest purchase in the order of increasing record_date:

```
select record_date,
    max(purchase_date) over (
        order by record_date
        ) as latest_purchase_date
from your_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to try this:

```
select recordDate, max(purchaseDate) from myDB 
 group by recordDate
```

I am assuming SQL Server.